# How to set up Rest template using a specific proxy for a specific HTTPS call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, proxy

I want to be able to call a specific HTTPS endpoint via proxy using rest templates

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("proxyRestTemplate")
public RestTemplate proxyRestTemplate() {
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();

    // Set the proxy type to SOCKS for HTTPS
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("proxyhost.com", 8080));
    requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);

    // Configure HTTPS support
    requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(5000); // Set your desired timeout
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(5000);

    // Create RestTemplate and set the request factory
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

    return restTemplate;
}
```

and in my class I am doing something like this

```
RestTemplate proxyRestTemplate;


public Stream<Entry> get() {

try {
  proxyRestTemplate.getInterceptors().add(
    new BasicAuthenticationInterceptor("user", "pass"));
  Stream<Entry> resultResponse =
    proxyRestTemplate.execute(
      "https address that returns a csv",
      HttpMethod.GET,
      null,
      clientHttpResponse -> {
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(clientHttpResponse.getBody());
        CsvToBean<Entry> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Entry>(reader)
          .withType(Entry.class)
          .withSeparator(',')
          .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
          .build();
        return csvToBean.stream();
      });   
} catch (Exception e) {
  ....
}
```

The ideea is to have all other endpoints into the app without proxy call that is why I created a separate restTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it's done in my application

```java
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.config.AuthSchemes;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
...
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
... 

    @Bean
    public CloseableHttpClient httpClient(
            @Value("${http.maxConnections}") int maxConnections,
            @Value("${http.useProxy}") boolean useProxy,
            @Value("${http.proxyHost:#{null}}") String proxyHost,
            @Value("${http.proxyPort:#{null}}") Integer proxyPort,
            @Value("${http.proxyUser:#{null}}") String proxyUser,
            @Value("${http.proxyPassword:#{null}}") String proxyPassword,
            @Value("${http.proxyDomain:#{null}}") String proxyDomain
    ) {
        if (useProxy) {
            HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);
            CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            credsProvider.setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope(proxy),
                    new NTCredentials(proxyUser, proxyPassword, null, proxyDomain)
            );
            RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig
                    .custom()
                    .setProxyPreferredAuthSchemes(asList(AuthSchemes.NTLM))
                    .setProxy(proxy)
                    .build();
            return HttpClientBuilder
                    .create()
                    .disableCookieManagement()
                    .disableRedirectHandling()
                    .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                    .setMaxConnPerRoute(maxConnections)
                    .setMaxConnTotal(maxConnections)
                    .build();
        } else {
            return HttpClientBuilder
                    .create()
                    .disableCookieManagement()
                    .disableRedirectHandling()
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory(CloseableHttpClient httpClient) {
        return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(
            RestTemplateBuilder templateBuilder,
            ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory
    ) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = templateBuilder.configure(new RestTemplate());
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: is it any reason why disableRedirectHandling ?

Comment: The REST API we are calling is a bit rubbish and will redirect to an html page in case of error (eg invalid login credentials) so we don't follow redirects

Comment: what did you add as setMaxConnPerRoute? How do you deiced on this ?

Comment: HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory required type is HttpClient not ClosableHttp client and building the  class leads to org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient